# Is there a free version of SQL server that has Integration Services Catalog too?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Trying to understand what free version of sql server allows to create Integration Services Catalog for SSIS pacakges. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

A licensed (dev/standard/enterprise) SQL Server installation is required to run SSIS packages at will.

Otherwise, SSIS execution only works from within the context of the Visual Studio, SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), debug environment.

Or, you can create one-time use SSIS packages via the Import/Export wizard in SSMS for Express editions. Those packages are source to sink - no opportunity for transformation steps, tasks, etc.